# iOS rotate image inside canvas with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, image, rotation, core-graphics, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate an image that is placed inside rect and is covering only part of it.

[image]

I've came to this solution but could not get image to be rotated:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // drawing some texts and lines

    // rotate myImage by 'angle'
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, imageOffset.x, imageOffset.y)
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, angle)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageOffset.x, -imageOffset.y)
    myImage?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: imageOffset.x, y: imageOffset.y, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))

    CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    // draw other stuff
}
```

Well, how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You're creating an image context, drawing an image into it, and then ending the context without ever outputting an image. Therefore you'll never see the output.

You'll want to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to get your rotated image out from the context, and then re-draw it in your view's context.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/// returns the transform equivalent of rotating a rect around its center
private func rotateTransformRectAroundCenter(rect:CGRect, angle:CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
    let t = CGAffineTransformConcat(
        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-rect.origin.x-rect.size.width*0.5, -rect.origin.y-rect.size.height*0.5),
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    )
    return CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.width*0.5, rect.size.height*0.5))
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // get current context
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // the rect to draw the image in
    let rect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300)

    // angle to rotate image by
    let angle = CGFloat(M_PI*0.25)

    // the image bounds
    let imgRect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: img.size)

    // transform of rotating image
    let imgRotate = rotateTransformRectAroundCenter(imgRect, angle: angle)

    // rotated image frame
    let rotatedImgFrame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, imgRotate)

    // transform of rotating image context
    let rotateContext = rotateTransformRectAroundCenter(rotatedImgFrame, angle: angle)


    // begin image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedImgFrame.size, false, img.scale)

    let imgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // rotate image context
    CGContextConcatCTM(imgContext, rotateContext)

    // draw image in context
    img.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: img.size))

    // get output from context
    let output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // end context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // get the rotated rect for the image to be drawn in the main context
    var outputRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rotateTransformRectAroundCenter(rect, angle: angle))
    outputRect.origin = CGPoint(x: outputRect.origin.x+rect.origin.x, y: outputRect.origin.y+rect.origin.y)

    // draw image
    output.drawInRect(outputRect)
}
```

Comment: I've updated example in question like you said but still no luck. Obviously there is and issue with rotation because I have to rotate the whole canvas not just image area.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case your original approach was correct. You should create a new image context to render your image in, then use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to output the rotated image which you can then draw in your view's context. I have updated my answer with an example of this.

Comment: I looks like a lot of overhead for such a basic thing. I've managed to do it a bit differently (hackish) but it works. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @BorutTomazin well bear in mind that you can always cache the rotated image generated from the image context, allowing you to redraw it without needing a new image context. But yes, I was surprised myself just how much code it takes to do this! Glad you found a solution though!